# Pagination using Request URL for WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, pagination

I am writing to seek help, in how can I implement a page number filter into the web api method below.  I am aware of the 'pagesize' and 'take' property but this only allowed me to filter number of records.

I would like to be able, to show all records but spread the data through number of pages such as api/test?name=frs&page=2

Please provide some help/guide into how I can start implementing this task further, thanks.

```
public HttpResponseMessage get([FromUri] Query query )
  {
        int pageSize = 10;
        int page = 0;

        IQueryable<data_qy> Data = null;

        var totalCount = Data.Count();
       // var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / pageSize);

       // var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);
       // var prevLink = page > 0 ? urlHelper.Link("DefaultApi", new { page = page - 1 }) : "";
       // var nextLink = page < totalPages - 1 ? urlHelper.Link("DefaultApi", new { page = page + 1 }) : "";

        Data = Data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate);

        var data = Data.Skip(pageSize * page).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        if (!data.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }

        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { totalCount, totalPages, prevLink, nextLink, data });
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { totalCount, data });
    }
```

Comment: "I would like to be able, to show all records but incremented between pages." what? so unclear it makes me wanna downvote

Comment: Apology for the not making the explanation clear, i have edited the above statement, to clarify my goal. Please advice further, if possible. Thanks

Comment: Your update *still* doesn't make sense. Are you trying to say that if someone passes page 2, you want to return both pages 1 *and* 2?

Comment: @user3070072 This still is somewhat unclear. Judging by your url it seems like you are just trying to do ordinary pagination. If that's what you are asking for you are doing a good job hiding your intentions with words... ALSO if you are asking how to make pagination work clearly you have to do homework rather than asking it on SO

Comment: if the query returns 20 records of data, i would like the each page to show 10 lines of records, hence if I call, `api/test?name=frs&page=1`, would show me first 10 records of the query and if I query `api/test?name=frs&page=2`, the page would show me second set of 10 records. I hope i have clarified the pagination issue clearly, if not, please do let me know. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I tried using pagesize property above and other commented out code, where I have attempted the pagination process but I was unable to filter pages, hence I am seeking little guide/process/explanation, what I need to look into further to make this work. Please advice further, if possible.

Comment: @user3070072 your explanation from 1 hour ago was indeed something people can work with. Information required to answer a question should be within the question - not comments. Can you tell me the namespace for the Query class parameter you got there? I don't know that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this combined with your pagination code:

```
        var pageValue = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString().Get("page");
        int currentPage;
        if (!int.TryParse(pageValue, out currentPage))
        {
            currentPage = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Dear Andreas, apology for the late response.  Thank you for your time and help.  I manage to get to work using your solution and making other couple of changes to the code. Many thanks for all your help and time.